# Need to interact with Hardware device like Cash Drawer using Electron JS

Tags: node.js, electron

I want to interact with hardware devices like Cash drawer using electron js. Sending some commands to open or close drawer. Help me providing some reference to implement same. Does electron support this ? or i need to use some other node package for this ?

Comment: Hi. Were you able to find any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the dll of the device to communincate [sample reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.devices.pointofservice.cashdrawer)
You can call dll using the electron-edge-js module to call dll methods from the electron
[link to electron edge js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/electron-edge-js)

Comment: I can not use .net libraries. i need to use some electron api itself directly or some npm modules